# Display filename of git diff filtered by term

Tags: grep, git

`-n` works as a grep argument to display the line number, but `-H` doesn't for filename.  I think it is because `git diff` doesn't by default output filename for each changed line.  As I was typing, I considered another option to display multiple lines and it solved my immediate problem, but would still like to know the solution to display the actual filename.

```
[michael@bigbox www]$ git diff | grep -n -H "this->config"
(standard input):614:-        $config=json_decode($this->config,true);
[michael@bigbox www]$
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I’m not sure you can show both the filename and the changed line in a single command, but the following will list all files where a line containing `this->config` has changed:

```
git diff --name-only -G"this->config"
```